# Is there a way to disable sorting in react-sortable--hoc

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I have a requirement where the sorting of the list depends on the state which can be toggled using a button. The user should be able to sort only when he is in the editing mode. So I need to disable the sorting of the list. Can anyone help me out on how to add the disabled key to the `SortableElement` in `react-sortable-hoc`. I tired to search a working example on google but couldn't find any. Can anyone out there help me out on this one?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the documentation, seems like `SortableElement` supports a disabled flag, you could set the disabled flag to:

```
<SortableItem ... disabled={editable}/>
```

Where `SortableItem` is a wrapper of `SortableElement`.

If you notice how `SortableElement` is defined, it just takes config where you can just pass the disabled flag. Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: Have any option to disabled drop on a item like draggable?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
<Sortable
    options={{disabled:true, ...}} > ...
```